# Eclipse git fetch from all repositories simultaneously

Tags: eclipse, git, fetch, egit

I am using several Git repositories in my Eclipse workspace. Is it possible to easily fetch from all repositories?

When I mark all repositories and right click them I can only pull but not fetch. So I have to fetch from each repository separately which is not very convenient.

I am using Egit 3.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented in Egit. There is a bug that describes the required feature: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349560